show a measure is absolutely continuous wrt lebesgue
Take a measure $\mu$ on $[0,T]\times \mathbb R^d$ and a positive mollifier $\eta^\delta$ on $\mathbb R^d$. Assume for all $\gamma :[0,T]\to \mathbb R_+$ with $\int_0^T \gamma(t)dt=1$ we have
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,T]\times\mathbb R^d}\eta^\delta(x-y)\gamma(t)\mu(dt,dy)\leq K
\end{align}
Lebesgue a.s. in x, for some constant $K$ which does not depend on $\delta$, $x\in\mathbb R^d$ or $\gamma$. Can we conclude $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue on $\mu$ on $[0,T]\times \mathbb R^d$ with density bounded by $K$?
